# How to get available attributes of an Invantive SQL provider

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql

There are several providers available for Invantive SQL. There are some shared provider attributes like `apiUrl` for Exact Online, but how can I without access to the source code determine the full list of configurable provider attributes available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a list of data dictionary views which contains more details on the possibilities.

For instance the list of providers can be retrieved using (connect first to any provider like the password-less 'Dummy'):

```
select * 
from   systemproviders
```

Depending on release you can only select the possible attributes for the currently connected data containers using:

```
select * 
from   systemdatacontainerattributes
```

Or use

```
select * 
from   systemproviderattributes
```